# pg_createcluster ssl cert behaviour different for 9.1 and 9.3 on Debian Squeeze

Tags: ssl, postgresql, cluster

I think i found a bug in pg_createcluster when creating a 9.3 cluster. At first, my configuration:
Debian Squeeze with PostgreSQL 9.1 from squeeze-backports and PostgreSQL 9.3 from apt.postgresql.org (official repos).

Installing the 9.3 source and PG 9.3 server besides the already running 9.1 cluster went fine but when creating new clusters i run into the following issue which i cant explain.

When creating another 9.1 cluster like this:
`pg_createcluster --locale=de_DE.UTF-8 9.1 test`
the cluster gets created and also the snakeoil cert and key are being symlinked into /var/lib/postgresql/9.1/test/ just like `man pg_createcluster` tells me.

But when doing this:
`pg_createcluster --locale=de_DE.UTF-8 9.3 test`
the cluster gets also created but cannot be started. In the default config ssl is true but pg_createcluster did not create the 2 symlinks for the snakeoil ssl certs like it did for 9.1. So while trying to start the 9.3 cluster it aborts and complains that the server.crt is missing.

Does anyone know why? I mean, i can just create the 2 symlinks with puppet myself, but thats not the best solution. Is this a bug or WHY does this happen!?

Answer (score 0):

It was my fault. Since 9.3 PostgreSQL does not symlink the files into the data folder anymore but instead uses the following two configuration options - which are cleaner.

`ssl_cert_file = '/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem'          # (change requires restart)
ssl_key_file = '/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key'         # (change requires restart)`